# Is this problem a geometric program?

Tags: optimization

$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
& \underset{x,y}{\text{minimize}} 
& & f_0(x,y) \label{eq:6}\\
& \text{subject to} 
& &  f_1(x)\geq 0, \label{eq:7} \\
& & & f_2(y)=0,\\
& & &  x \in \{0,1\}^n, y\in\mathbb{R}^n. \label{eq:9} 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
$$

where $f_0(x)$ and $f_1(x)$ are linear functions. The function $f_2(x)$ is a monomial of the form
$$
f_2(y)=-c+\prod_{i=1}^ny_i,
$$
for some $c>0$.

How can I solve the following problem? Is it a geometric programming problem?
What is the name of this problem and is there any tool to solve it?

Comment: $f_2$ constraints the $y$ part to some knd of hyper surface, probably hyperbolic (at least for $n=2$)..

Comment: Depends on the signs of the coefficients in $f_0$ and $f_1$.

Comment: If $y_i>0$ you can apply $\log$ on $c = \prod_{i=1}^n y_i$ and obtain $c = \sum_{i=1}^n \log y_i$. This would yield a mixed-integer programming.

Comment: This transformation keeps the problem nonlinear, right?

Comment: I added a longer answer to your question, could you take a look?
If it does not solve your problem could you give some indications on how to improve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will answer it so I can have more space for explain myself.

If $y_i>0$ you can apply $\log$ on $c=\prod^{n}_{i=1} y_i$ and obtain $\log c=\sum^n_{i=1}\log y_i$.

Now call $w_i = \log y_i$, then the constraint become $\log c=\sum^n_{i=1} w_i$, which is a *linear constraint*. Since $c$ is a parameter you can have $k = \log c$ being a parameter as well.

If you are able to change your objective function,
\begin{align}
    f_0(x,y) = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i y_i + \sum^n_{i=1}b_i x_i
\end{align}
in order to fit $w_i$ in the place of $y_i$, you could find some $\widetilde{a}_i$
such that
\begin{align}
    f_0(x,y) = \sum_{i=1}^n \widetilde{a}_i w_i + \sum^n_{i=1}b_i x_i
\end{align}
Then, this would yield a mixed-integer programming.
Note that minimizing $w_i$ imply minimizing $y_i$.

---

Alternatively, if you can not change your parameter $a_i$ in the objective function. 
Consider that you have 
\begin{align}
    f_0(x,y) = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i y_i + \sum^n_{i=1}b_i x_i
\end{align}
if $w_i = \log y_i$ then $y_i = e^{w_i}$.
Therefore
\begin{align}
    f_0(x,y) = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i e^{w_i} + \sum^n_{i=1}b_i x_i
\end{align}
Which is a nonlinear but *convex* objective function.

The problem becomes a convex constrained Mixed Integer Convex Programming with linear constraints which can be solved easily.
Which can be solved to global optimality with BONMIN (free and also available in NEOS Solver).

Answer (score 1):

If coefficients in f0 and f1 are positive, all variables are positive, and you frame the $y$ constraints as $c = \prod_{i=1}^n y_i$ then yes. But you're better off with Marco's solution above: use a mixed-integer linear programming solver, which you can find for any programming language you like.

If you do want to solve geometric programs, take a look at [GPkit](http://gpkit.rtfd.org). No mixed-integer support yet, but we're working on it.

Comment: Thank you. But Macro's solution gives a nonlinear constraint. Isn't it?